# tabularx repeat headers at the start of each new page

Tags: tables, macros, environments, longtable, tabu

I am trying to write a latex template for math dissertations for my university and I have gotten most of the formating built into the appropriate class file. However, one issue that I'm not sure how to solve is their requirements for tables. They need to be full-text-width (which I achieve fine with using tabularx environment), have dedicated headers (which is easy enough), and have a title/label (again, not too difficult). The part I'm having trouble with is the following: If the table extends to be past the current page, it should be split and continued on the next page with a reference to the table's title with "continued" appended, the headers need to be restated, and then the table continued. So far the following is my general idea of structuring a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\dissertationTable}[5]{
    \begin{table}
    \centering
        \caption{#4}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{#1}
        #2\\ \hline% This is the header line
        #3\\ \hline% This is the body of the table, 
                   % which should include all the relevant line breaks etc.
        \end{tabularx}
        \label{#5}
    \end{table}
    }
\begin{document}

\dissertationTable{lXX}{These & Are & Headings}{These are & some rows& to see\\ how it & works & and to\\ demonstrate & how to & enter info.}{Some Table}{tableref}

\end{document}
```

The above works decently well to make a table, and I could reuse the `#2` argument to reprint the heading if I could detect a pagebreak, and use the label in the `#5` argument to cite the name (or just use the #4 caption directly) and append "continue". But I am not sure how to detect the pagebreak automatically. I also have issues trying to get the entire header in bold text and none of the content in bold text; the alignment tabs seem to break the scope of the `\bfseries` command.

I looked into this more generally and saw the `longtable` package and/or the `tabu` package, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax correctly to get what I'm after. I'm pretty sure the `tabu` package is capable of doing most/everything I want and I'm probably just being dumb, but I can't get it to compile more than a basic table without errors so I'm doing something stupid.

Regardless of whether one uses tabu or some clever macro, my goal is to generate some kind of command or environment that hides as much off the require formatting as possible (most of the students using this template will have very minimal TeX understanding, so the less they need to know the better). Ideally I'd use something that detects the number of align characters and allows me to set the left/right align characters within the command itself, instead of requiring it of the student (eg the first argument; `{lXX}`, in the MWE above).

Thus, if someone could either help me out with the syntax with longtable/tabu or explain how to detect a page break to make such a command myself, I'd very much appreciate it. And if there is a nice way to preformat the table for the alignment of each column without knowing how many columns there will be, that would be the cherry on top.

Thanks!

Comment: (i) long table should not be enclosed in `table` environment, (ii) `longtable` (as well `longtabu`)   have special syntax for repeating column headers and footers on each page, which (so far) are not part of your command and are superfluous at  tables shorter than one page (it is described in these package documentation) , (iii)  frankly said, i don't see any benefits in table design using your command `\dissertationTable`, i would rather stick with standard approach at writing of tables.

Comment: Zarko, I agree; the command I included was by way of showing the kind of thing I'm after as a MWE, not a suggestion that I want to have a special command. I have thus far failed at figuring out the correct syntax for the longtable to get it to work spanning multiple pages, but I think longtable or longtabu would be the ideal solution if I could get it to work. 

That being said, I would also like to know if there is a way to detect a page break in TeX or LaTeX as that would be a useful thing to know for a horde of other things I'm likely to come across in the future.

Comment: as examples of the use `longtable` and `ltablex` packages see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392512, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368444/. ˙longtabu` is based on `longtable` so the specific syntax for long tables are the same.  for details read documentations for those packages. beside mentioned packages for long table exist many others (`supertabular` etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an example of using `longtabu` table with repeated headers and footers:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
    \tabulinesep = ^2mm_2mm
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth { l X[1,l] X[1,l]}
    \caption{Some table}
\label{tablere}                             \\
    \tabucline [1pt] -
These & Are & Headings                      \\
    \tabucline -
\endfirsthead
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Some table \hfill(continued)}            \\
    \tabucline [1pt]-
These & Are & Headings                      \\
    \tabucline -
\endhead
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \tabucline [1pt]-
\endlastfoot
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% table body
    \everyrow{\tabucline - }
first row   & \lipsum*[2]    & \lipsum*[2]  \\
%    \midrule
second row  & \lipsum*[13]   & \lipsum*[13] \\
%    \midrule
third row  & \lipsum*[23]   & \lipsum*[23]  \\
%    \midrule
forth row   & \lipsum*[32]   & \lipsum*[32] \\
%    \midrule
fifth row   & \lipsum*[42]   & \lipsum*[43] \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

note:

- for the final form of the table, the document must be compiled at least twice
- tables used `longtable` and `longtabu` (as well others) can break between pages only between rows and not inside them. consequently at long cells' contents can arose empty spaces below some parts of tables
- (**edit**) for use of `longtabe` from package `tabu` you should be aware, that this package is still broken. see @Ulrike Fischer comment below answer.
- `tabularx` is intended for (short) tables (usually enclosed in `table` float  environment), which can be fit on one page
- `tabularx` can be extend to long table by use of the package `ltablex`:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt]{book}
  \usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
  \usepackage{booktabs,ltablex}    % <---
      \keepXColumns
  \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l X X}
      \caption{Some table}
  \label{tablere}                             \\
      \toprule
  These & Are & Headings                      \\
      \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
      \caption{Some table \hfill(continued)}            \\
      \toprule
  These & Are & Headings                      \\
      \midrule
  \endhead
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
  \endfoot
      \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  % table body
  first row   & \lipsum*[2]    & \lipsum*[2]  \\
      \midrule
  second row  & \lipsum*[13]   & \lipsum*[13] \\
      \midrule
  third row  & \lipsum*[23]   & \lipsum*[23]  \\
      \midrule
  forth row   & \lipsum*[32]   & \lipsum*[32] \\
      \midrule
  fifth row   & \lipsum*[42]   & \lipsum*[43] \\
  \end{tabularx}

  \end{document}
  ```

result is similar as before.  for more details about settings long tables read documentation of packages which you use.

Comment: tabu is currently broken in various places. See the issue list at https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu. I would recommend not to use it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer,  recently version (2.10) has added some bug fixes (thanks to David), so it works now better than original version (2.8). i know that it still contains bugs, but  in most cases it works sufficiently reliably. i will add one another solution with use of `ltablex` asap.

Comment: @zarko 2.10 is not released see also David's comment at https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/1

Comment: @albert, how than i have it? i only update my  MikTeX installation ... i'm aware  that it still not have (officially) new maintainer). if you will check my previous answers regarding `tabu` you will see, that i newer recommend to use `tabu` and always warn op at its use. so in my answer i only show, how to define column headers at  `longtabu` (as well at `ltablex` version of long tables) and not recommend to use it. anyway, thank you for your concern.

Comment: @Zarko I know that some of the bugs has been fixed - one of them is actually from me - but I also know that some more are lurking in the code, I saw e.g. questions about it in a german group, and it will take weeks or month to sort them out as neither David nor me nor other from the team have much time to look into it and the maintainer doesn't do it, so better add to *every* answer with tabu a very large warning.

Comment: I don't know how you got it in your MikTex version, looking at the site  I see, at e.g. http://mirror.easyname.ch/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/?C=M;O=D, tabu.tar.lzma 2019-01-19 22:11