# Listing inside table

Tags: tables, minipage, minted

I've tried to make table with minted listing inside using minipage, but my listing takes up more than one page and it turns out that part of the text is cut off, is it possible to make minipage for several pages or is there some other environment to make it work properly?

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}{|l|}
        \hline
             \textbf{URL} \\ \hline 
             /api/test \\ \hline
             \textbf{Method} \\ \hline
             GET \\ \hline
             \textbf{Headers} \\ \hline 
             - \\ \hline
             \textbf{Params} \\ \hline
             \textit{limit} - items count \\
             \textit{offset} - start index \\ \hline
             \textbf{Response} \\ \hline
             \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
             \inputminted[fontsize=\footnotesize,breaklines]{js}{test.json}
             \end{minipage}
        \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `minipage` can be only on one page. Why you like to have `minipage` inside `longtable?

Comment: @Zarko because that's the only way I found to put a listing in a table

Comment: (i) you was provide only code fragment, which is not possible to test (ii) instead `minipage` try to use column type `p{\linewidth}` . see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392512/formatting-issue-when-combining-landscapethreeparttabletabularxcan or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368444/ can help you.

Comment: What is the purpose of a `longtable` with just one column?